# Remove one letter words from cells (which are lists) in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Assume I have the following pd.DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'trial_num': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
     'subject': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
     'samples': [['I', 'am', 'here'],
                 ['where', 'are', 'you'],
                 ['I', 'c', 'u'],
                 ['where', 'am', 'I'],
                 ['X', 'j', 'am'],
                 ['low', 'high']]
    }
)
```

I would like to remove all the single letter words in each list (in `samples` column).
Is there a pythonic way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list comprehension:

```
df['samples'] = df['samples'].map(lambda x: [y for y in x if len(y) > 1])
print (df)
   trial_num  subject            samples
0          1        1         [am, here]
1          2        1  [where, are, you]
2          3        1                 []
3          1        2        [where, am]
4          2        2               [am]
5          3        2        [low, high]
```

Answer (score 2):

List comprehension is pretty pythonic:

```
df.samples = [[w for w in s if len(w) > 1] for s in df.samples]
```

Output:

```
   trial_num  subject            samples
0          1        1         [am, here]
1          2        1  [where, are, you]
2          3        1                 []
3          1        2        [where, am]
4          2        2               [am]
5          3        2        [low, high]
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do that in the following way.

```
df['samples'] = df['samples'].map(lambda l: [item for item in l if len(item) != 1])
df
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternate answer:

```
# Function to remove
def rem(s):
    [s.remove(i) for i in s if (len(i)==1)]
    return s

# Apply function
df['samples'] = df['samples'].apply(lambda x: rem(x))
```

Output:

```
   trial_num  subject            samples
0          1        1         [am, here]
1          2        1  [where, are, you]
2          3        1                 []
3          1        2        [where, am]
4          2        2               [am]
5          3        2        [low, high]
```